# How to schedule running vlc on MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, vlc, macos

I have created a m3u list file for some mp3 files.

How could I schedule the macbook to play it, e.g. tomorrow 6am?

Answer (score 2):

Open Automator and do something like this.

Use Workflow + Drag New Calendar Event to the right. Choose the time+date. Choose what file to open.

[image: new cal event]

Obviously set the date/time and choose the right file to Open.

Comment: You may have to point it to open the m3u file, and not VLC.app.  Maybe.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I don't get it, after I click Automator, which one shall I choose, Workflow, Application, Service, Print Plugin, Folder Action, iCal Alarm, or Image Capture Plugin?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you can see it. If you pay close attention at the top of the screen shot it shows it to be "Workflow".